# Sorting on Crystal Reports Data using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Now i am working on crystal reports to display the sales details. I used adodb connection and data set for dynamically populate the data on my crystal reports.

My Output likes show this format,

```
Inv.No     Vendor   Salevalue  Tax   Total

 R1          xxx       10000    100   10100
 R10         yyy       15000    500   15500
 R2          zzz       1000      10    1010
 R3          vvv       2500      50    2550
```

Expected Output is,

```
  Inv.No     Vendor   Salevalue   Tax   Total

  R1          xxx       10000    100   10100
  R2          zzz       1000      10    1010
  R3          vvv       2500      50    2550
  R10         yyy       15000    500   15500
```

Actually i used Inv.No wise Sorting option on my report.

Comment: Are you fine filtering/sorting the data from SQL ? if so I have answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was in your position, instead of doing it in Crystal report I will do it through sql and this will give me exact sort order I need. Later I will move same data to Crystal report with column value to display.

```
select
 CAST(SUBSTRING(yourColName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', yourColName), 
 LEN(yourColName)) AS INT) RL_Num
FROM TableName
ORDER BY  RL_Num
```

This will be your output from SQL so in Crystal report.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the column "Inv.No" is a string type and the sorting is "correct" because that is the way strings sort. You could have a background column that has only the numeric value of "Inv.No" and sort by that.
A second but less elegant solution is to sort by a field that has the value

```
Right("              " & {Inv.No},15)
```

so that it's aligned like a number but I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `Inv. No` column contains string text, it sorts the column alphabetically, which places R10 between R1 and R2.  To correct this and sort them numerically, you will need to create a new column of data that contains only numeric data.

If your `Inv. No` data is always consistent in the format of 1 character followed by nothing but numbers, you could use a formula field with the following formula to capture the numeric data, then sort the records using this formula field.

```
ToNumber(Mid ({Table.Inv_No}, 2));
```

However, if there is any possibility that the data may not be numeric then this will only throw an error.

The best way to fix this would be to edit your data source either in VB.NET or SQL to include a numeric column to control your sorts.  The formula approach can work in a pinch, but if the structure of your invoice numbers ever changes, then it can break the report if it conflicts with the formula in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The following formula is about the same as in R. McMillan's answer, but with some error checking
The report will not break, even if the invoice number is empty or in a different format.

```
If Not IsNull({yourTable.InvNo}) Then
    If IsNumeric(Replace({yourTable.InvNo}, "R","")) Then
        ToNumber(Replace({yourTable.InvNo}, "R",""))
    Else
        -1
Else
    -1
```

(Invoices with a different format will appear on top.)